# PuffLoader, react spinner

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plugins, react-spinners

in this code `PuffLoader` was used `from react-spinners` **plugin** for loader

`component code`

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import PuffLoader from "react-spinners/PuffLoader";

const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;
export default function Loading ({size}:{size:number}) {
  return (
     <PuffLoader css={override} size={size || 60} />;

  );
}
```

found this on `css` attribute when passed to `PuffLoader` component

`error`

```
Type '{ css: SerializedStyles; size: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LoaderSizeProps'.Property 'css' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LoaderSizeProps'
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of react-spinners no longer has `@emotion/react` as a dependency. You can just pass a style object

```
import React from "react";
import PuffLoader from "react-spinners/PuffLoader";

const override = {
  display: 'block',
  margin: '0 auto',
  borderColor: 'red'
};

export default function Loading ({size}:{size:number}) {
  return (
     <PuffLoader cssOverride={override} size={size || 60} />
  );
}
```

That should work.